# How to sort object array by value deep inside array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, drupal, drupal-7

I have this array:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [tid] => 26001835
    [vid] => 5
    [name] => AppleTV
    [description] => My description
    [format] => filtered_html
    [weight] => 0
    [vocabulary_machine_name] => how_to_watch_device
    [field_device_image] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fid] => 26608990
                            [alt] => 
                            [title] => 
                            [width] => 194
                            [height] => 102
                            [uid] => 26000697
                            [filename] => Apple-TV.png
                            [uri] => public://Apple-TV.png
                            [filemime] => image/png
                            [filesize] => 2103
                            [status] => 1
                            [timestamp] => 1405346182
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_buy_now_button_link] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => http://www.something.com
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => http://www.something.com
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_learn_more] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => http://something.com/somepage
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => http://something.com/somepage
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_device_category] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => network
                        )

                )

        )

)
stdClass Object
(
    [tid] => 26001834
    [vid] => 5
    [name] => Playstation - USA
    [description] => My description
    [format] => filtered_html
    [weight] => 2
    [vocabulary_machine_name] => how_to_watch_device
    [field_device_image] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fid] => 26608991
                            [alt] => 
                            [title] => 
                            [width] => 194
                            [height] => 102
                            [uid] => 26000697
                            [filename] => ps4network.png
                            [uri] => public://ps4network.png
                            [filemime] => image/png
                            [filesize] => 4566
                            [status] => 1
                            [timestamp] => 1405346218
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_buy_now_button_link] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => http://www.somesite.com
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => http://somesite.com
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_learn_more] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_device_category] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => blast_areas
                        )

                )

        )

)
stdClass Object
(
    [tid] => 26001836
    [vid] => 5
    [name] => Brighthouse Networks
    [description] => My description
    [format] => filtered_html
    [weight] => 3
    [vocabulary_machine_name] => how_to_watch_device
    [field_device_image] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fid] => 26608993
                            [alt] => 
                            [title] => 
                            [width] => 194
                            [height] => 102
                            [uid] => 26000697
                            [filename] => brighthouse.png
                            [uri] => public://brighthouse.png
                            [filemime] => image/png
                            [filesize] => 8392
                            [status] => 1
                            [timestamp] => 1405358781
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_buy_now_button_link] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_learn_more] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_device_category] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => ppv_provider
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to sort the array by the array by the value in field_device_category.  Basically, I want to group the results but first I need to make sure all the objects are sorted by field_device_category.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `usort` for this kind of sorting. It uses Quicksort in the background and takes a user-defined function to compare the array elements:

```
usort($array, "complicatedArrayComparer");
function complicatedArrayComparer($a,$b)
{
    if ($a['field_device_category'] == $b['field_device_category']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['field_device_category'] < $b['field_device_category']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  The entries for ['field_device_category'] need to be targeted to where ['field_device_category'] appears in the array, correct?

Something like ->field_device_category['und'][0]['value'], right?

Comment: That's right. You just get the array elements as parameters for the function. The only thing you do is compare which one of the array elements is bigger and return 1 (first one is bigger), 0 (equal) or -1 (second one).